# Задать видимость UserControl'в через свойство

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пытаюсь изменить видимость `Visibility` через забинденое свойство к `UserControl'у` по нажатию кнопки, параллельно к этому свойству для проверки привязал другую кнопку. В итоге видимость кнопки изменяется а видимость `UserControl'a` нет. Как решить данную проблему?

Xaml MainUI

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button
        Grid.Row="0"
        Height="40"
        Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
        Content="Click" />
    <ucerControls:FirstUC Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding FirstViewModel}" />
    <ucerControls:SecondUC
        Grid.Row="2"
        DataContext="{Binding SecondViewModel}"
        Visibility="{Binding Visible}" />
    <Button
        Grid.Row="3"
        Height="30"
        Content="{Binding Text}"
        Visibility="{Binding Visible}" />
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region PropertyChangedEventHandler
    /// <summary>
    /// Метод проверяющий изменилось ли свойство
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    private FirstViewModel _firstViewModel;
    private SecondViewModel _secondViewModel;
    private string _visible;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        FirstViewModel=new FirstViewModel();
        SecondViewModel=new SecondViewModel();
        Visible = "Collapsed";

        ClickCommand = new Command(arg =>
        {
            Visible =(Visible=="Collapsed")?"Visible":"Collapsed";
        });
    }

    public FirstViewModel FirstViewModel
    {
        get { return _firstViewModel; }
        set { _firstViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("FirstViewModel");}
    }

    public SecondViewModel SecondViewModel
    {
        get { return _secondViewModel; }
        set { _secondViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("SecondViewModel");}
    }

    public string Visible
    {
        get { return _visible; }
        set { _visible = value; OnPropertyChanged("Visible"); }
    }

    public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }
}
```

В других `UserControl'ах` покрашен `Background` для видимости

Comment: Кстати если подключение DataContext убрать то все работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию привязка идет к `DataContext`, так как вы меняете его - вы должны явно указать источник привязки, например так:

```
Visibility="{Binding DataContext.Visible,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
```

---

Такая ситуация возникает достаточно часто, когда нужно привязаться не к своему `DataContext`, а к `DataContext` родительского окна, поэтому для упрощения разметки можно написать простое расширение разметки:

```
class ParentWindowBindingExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public ParentWindowBindingExtension() { }

    public ParentWindowBindingExtension(string path)
    {
        Path = path;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return
            new Binding(Path)
            {
                RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor)
                {
                    AncestorType = typeof(Window)
                }
            }.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```

Тогда наша привязка сократится до лаконичного:

```
Visibility="{ex:ParentWindowBinding DataContext.Visible}"
```

где `ex` - пространство имен с этим классом.

Comment: Благодарю, пока ждал ответ уже понял что у меня привязка пыталась найти свойство из другого ViewModel так как сработала привязка к DataContext. Но решил это через перекидывание свойста, ваш подход больше нравится. Спасибо больше.

Comment: Теперь буду пробовать скрыть этот же UC  из первого FirstUC.

Comment: @KJfe, добавил способ сокращения разметки с такими привязками