# Передача ссылки на самого себя в параметре команды

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Привет всем. Хотел бы узнать 2 момента по поводу MVVM + WPF.
Первый момент легкий, хотел бы узнать, как передать в команду параметр, при срабатывании, на самого себя, через XAML.
У меня есть такой код:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentProducts}">
...
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding RequestCalculatorPriceProduct}" CommandParameter="{?????}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
...
</ItemsControl>
```

Соответственно `CurrentProducts` - является коллекцией объектов `IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>`. У каждый `ProductViewModel` выглядит так:

```
public class ProductViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Int64    Id { get; set; }
    public string   Name { get; set; }
    public string   Foto { get; set; }

    public ICommand RequestCalculatorPriceProduct { get; }

    public ProductViewModel( Int64 id, string name, string foto )
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Foto = foto;

        RequestCalculatorPriceProduct   =   new RelayCommand<ProductViewModel>( OnCalculatorPriceProductRequest );
    }

    private void OnCalculatorPriceProductRequest( ProductViewModel currentProduct )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Мне нужно в обработчике `OnCalculatorPriceProductRequest` в параметре принимать ссылку на самого себя.

Итак, из вышесказанного уже видно что подход не достаточно верный, поэтому я сразу задаю вопрос на второй момент, который очень тесно связан с предыдущим:
Коллекция `IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> CurrentProducts` у меня лежит во `ViewModel` страницы. Так вот, мне на самом деле бы хотелось, чтобы команда, которая сейчас в `ProductViewModel` была именно в `ViewModel` страницы, и при срабатывании команды, обработчик в параметре имел тот объект `ProductViewModel`, по которому щелкнули.

Как бы я не старался это сделать, у меня не получается.
Вот примерный код `ViewModel` страницы:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BasePageViewModel
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> CurrentProducts
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
    public ICommand RequestCalculatorPriceProduct { get; }
    ...
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        RequestCalculatorPriceProduct = new RelayCommand<ProductViewModel>( OnCalculatorPriceProductRequest );
        ...
    }
    private void OnCalculatorPriceProductRequest( ProductViewModel currentProduct )
    {
        // Я хочу вот тут получать выбранный ProductViewModel
    }
    ...     
}
```

Но с той разметкой XAML, которую я показал выше, это не работает. Команда вообще не срабатывает. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? И как реализовать следующие моменты, которые я описал

Comment: `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`

Comment: А почему вы в `OnCalculatorPriceProductRequest` не можете просто использовать `this`? Зачем вам этот параметр вообще?

Comment: По поводу второго вопроса вам нужно воспользоваться RelativeSource, примерно как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746587/218063

Comment: @VladD, автору команда нужна в MainVm, но он не знает как правильно привязаться, я так понимаю

Comment: @Андрей: Ну, в первой половине вопроса команда в `ProductViewModel`.

Comment: @Андрей, именно! Мне нужна команда в MainPageViewModel, подписать на нее обработчик с параметром пункта, на который нажму. Я все сделал, только не могу понять, как кнопку подвязать на эту команду, так как она хочет привязываться только на команду, которая во внутренней VM

Comment: Не могу найти правильный дубликат. Дело в том, что ItemsControl устанавливает своим элементам DataContext, поэтому вам нужно воспользоваться RelativeSource, как по ссылке выше

Comment: `<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.RequestCalculatorPriceProduct, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [WPF не работает Binding на FontSize внутри DataTemplate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/724592/wpf-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-binding-%d0%bd%d0%b0-fontsize-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-datatemplate)

Comment: Блин, что-то не работает... А что нужно передавать в AncestorType

Comment: А MainPageViewModel вы как устанавливаете в качестве контекста?

Comment: Я ввел базовый класс BasePage<VM> where VM :BasePageViewModel, который внутри себя, создает ViewModel и задает его в качестве контекста. Потом когда наследуюсь, устанавливаю нужную VM в параметре дженерика и все

Comment: Покажите как вы устанавливаете DataContext окну или что там у вас

Comment: У меня только одно окно со своим VM, которое управляет переходами между страницами. Каждая страница наследуется от `BasePage<VM> : Page where VM : BasePageViewModel`. В этом базовом классе для страниц, объявлено свойство, при установке которого задается контекст в сеттере:   `set
   {
    if( viewModel == value )
     return;

    viewModel = value;
    this.DataContext = viewModel;
   }`

Comment: У вас Page, ну значит AncestorType=Page

Comment: @Андрей Работает. Спасибо большое. А не могли бы объяснить, как за счет такой привязки `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` он понимает, какой конткретно `ProductViewModel` передавать?

Comment: Как я и говорю, ItemsControl устанавливает каждому элементу элемент из привязанной коллекции в качестве DataContext