# WPF Binding не через DataContext не видит свойство

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, bindingsource

В классе окна имеется свойство `TvNodes`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Node> TvNodes { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        VCSData xtv = new VCSData();

        TvNodes = xtv.TvNode;
        //this.DataContext = xtv.TvNode; <- так работает
    }
```

Как привязаться к нему в XAML, не устанавливая `DataContext`?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="VCSList" DataType="{x:Type local:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Check}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView
        Name="VCSTreeView"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VCSList}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding TvNodes}"
        <[!- ItemsSource="{Binding}"- так работает если положить данные в DataContext -]>
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        SelectedItemChanged="VCSTreeView_SelectedItemChanged"/>
    <TextBlock Text="--------------" x:Name="txt" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы ожидаете, что `ItemsSource="{Binding TvNodes}"` должно работать без указания `DataContext`?

Comment: Я спрашиваю как это сделать, через `local:` или ещё какие дерективы в области биндинга.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос. Пока ничего не понятно: ни что вы хотите получить, ни что пробовали сделать.

Comment: ? что пробывал сделать? ..там что то нехватает? кодов, примеров, описания?

Comment: `TvNodes` это не структура

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойство `TvNodes` принадлежит вашему окну, поэтому можно до него добраться через `RelativeSource` в режиме `FindAncestor`:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding TvNodes,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
```

<sub>(если в разметке получается много таких конструкций, их можно укоротить с помощью самописного расширения разметки как показано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746587/218063))</sub>

или с помощью `ElementName`:

```
<Window ... Name="myWindow">
    ...
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TvNodes, ElementName=myWindow}"
```

Comment: Спасибо, я пытался через `DependencyProperty` добраться, но что то пошло не так..