# Как удалять элемент из ListBox по кнопке, которая находится внутри этого ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
<ListBox Name="Player" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Height="200" Width="300">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                        <TextBlock Text="ID : " Margin="2"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="2"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Name : " Margin="2"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2"/>
                        <Button Width="20"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы можно было удалять элемент из ObservableCollection при нажатии на кнопку, которая находится в одной строчке с элементом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: использовать MVVM и удалять из вью модели.

Comment: [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1238287/373567)

Comment: @aepot, спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: Не разглядел поначалу кнопки, вот [еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116136/373567).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [WPF Binding не через DataContext не видит свойство](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881091/wpf-binding-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-datacontext-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать биндинг кнопки которая внутри элемента ListView WPF MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115981/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-listview-wpf-mvvm)

Answer (score -1):

Можно использовать команду с параметром. Команда находится как правило на том уровне где и список. Нужно перейти на этот уровень и привязать ее. Для этой цели можно привязывать через `ElementName`:

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=listbox, Path=DataContext.RemovePlayerCommand}"
```

и передавать в качестве параметра сам объект(просто оставить пустой binding):

```
CommandParameter="{Binding }"
```

в итоге выглядеть будет так:

```
<ListBox Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Players}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                <TextBlock Text="ID : " Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Name : " Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2"/>
                <Button Width="60" Content="удалить" 
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=Player, Path=DataContext.RemovePlayerCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

VM:

```
public class MainVM : BaseVM
{
    DelegateCommand<Player> removePlayerCommand;

    public ICommand RemovePlayerCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (removePlayerCommand == null)
            {
                removePlayerCommand = new DelegateCommand<Player>(removePlayerExecute);
            }
            return removePlayerCommand;
        }
    }

    private void removePlayerExecute(Player obj)
    {
        Players.Remove(obj);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Player> Players { get; set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        Players = new ObservableCollection<Player>();

        Players.Add(new Player() { Id = 1, Name = "ETH" });
        Players.Add(new Player() { Id = 2, Name = "BTC" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы используете не чистый WPF, а какой-то MVVM фреймворк. Указывайте в ответе, какой и почему.

Comment: @aepot, нет, чистый. Реализацию DelegateCommand можно найти в интернете, либо заменить на RelayCommand, которую также можно найти.

Comment: Так напишите об этом в ответе, и про `BaseVM` тоже.

Comment: @aepot, вы слишком зациклены на написании развернутых ответов. то что BaseVM это реализация INPC, а DelegateCommand - ICommand итак понятно и не всегда расписывалось в аналогичных ответах...

Comment: Без проблем, ваше право.